# Solving $\ddot y=\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the title states I am trying to solve $\ddot y=\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}$ with initial conditions $\dot y(t=0)=0$ and $\ddot y(t=0)=i$, I'm aware of the trick to evaluate this differential but I'm having trouble executing it. The trick is multiplying both sides by $\dot y$ giving us: $$\dot y \ddot y=\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}\dot y\Longrightarrow \dot y d\dot y=\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}dy$$, integrating both sides from $t=0$ to $t=t$, $\frac{\dot y(t)^2}{2}-\frac{\dot y(0)^2}{2}=\frac{\dot y^2}{2}-\frac{i^2}{2}=\frac{\dot y^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{e^{-y}}{2}+c $

$$e^{-y}=-1-\dot y^2+c\Longrightarrow y(t)=-\ln(-1-\dot y^2)+c^{'} \\ 
y(t=0)=0=-\ln(-1-i^2)+c^{'}=0+c^{'}, c^{'}=0$$

Although I have an odd feeling this is incorrect since two negatives inside the $\ln$ function doesn't look too promising.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\implies \ddot{y} dy = \frac12 e^{-y} dy$?

Comment: Yea I see what you're saying, it should've been $\dot y d\dot y=\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}dy$ but I don't think that changes the answer?

Comment: You have $i$ in the equations, so don't be startled by negatives in logarithm (even if it's wrong in this case)... but you should be alarmed by a zero in a logarithm, and the fact that you did $\ln 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is
$$
\int_{0}^{t}\dot{y}d\dot{y} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t}e^{-y}dy,
$$
$$
\dot{y}(t)^2 = e^{-y(t)} - e^{-y(0)}.
$$
You can surely solve this by expressing $t$ as an integral of $y$, but I don't think you can find an analytic expression for $y$ as a function of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Qiyu Wen
$$t=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{e^{-y}-c}}\\=\int\frac{e^{y/2}dy}{\sqrt{1-ce^y}}$$
then substitute $e^{y/2}=z$